# How to select data from MySQL table where a column is NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I expect the following code to show me all the records in the table where the exchange column is null but the result set show 0 rows. Any idea why?

```
SELECT * FROM pubco WHERE exchange IS NULL;
```

Comment: Either the table is empty or the there isn't any null value in the exchange column

Comment: there's no row with exchange NULL ! (maybe a DEFAULT value in the exchange column ?)

Comment: Perhaps what you think is NULL is actually the empty string `''`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

maybe you have interpreted `''` as `NULL` which is not the same, but try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM pubco 
WHERE exchange IS NULL OR
      exchange = ''
```

but if still not getting the value, maybe it has spaces on it, so you should `TRIM` it,

```
SELECT * 
FROM pubco 
WHERE exchange IS NULL OR
      TRIM(exchange) = ''
```

Comment: you have nailed it. The problem was my interpretation of `NULL` vs. `''` thanks for your help. Will accept answer when I can.

Answer (score 0):

One important remark: `NULL` and `''` (i.e. empty string) are not the same thing, most probably your column contains empty strings, so you need to put another condition:

```
SELECT * FROM pubco WHERE (exchange IS NULL OR exchange = '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure they are null?

Maybe they have a string value "NULL" that is not the same, what does it returns if you do:

```
SELECT * FROM pubco WHERE exchange == "NULL";
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM pubco 
WHERE exchange IS NULL OR
      exchange = ''
```

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM pubco 
WHERE isnull(exchange,'')='';
```

It will improve your **performance**.