# How to use NULL or empty string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, where-clause

I would like to know how to use NULL and an empty string at the same time in a `WHERE` clause in SQL Server. I need to find records that have either null values or an empty string. Thanks.

Comment: There's an OR keyword in SQL.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select data from MySQL table where a column is NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279947/how-to-select-data-from-mysql-table-where-a-column-is-null)  (this was a MySQL question, but it's basically the same answer for t-sql)

Answer (score 367, accepted):

```
Select *
From Table
Where (col is null or col = '')
```

Or

```
Select *
From Table
Where IsNull(col, '') = ''
```

Comment: according to @Bradc 's answer in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable?lq=1, better to use the first approach.

Comment: Also note that the comments say that In MSSQL 2016, there is no execution plan difference between using ISNULL in WHERE as opposed to using OR in WHERE. It's said that they both use the index on 'col' and do an index seek.

Answer (score 65):

If you need it in **SELECT** section can use like this.

```
SELECT ct.ID, 
       ISNULL(NULLIF(ct.LaunchDate, ''), null) [LaunchDate]
FROM   [dbo].[CustomerTable] ct
```

You can replace the `null` with your substitution value.

Comment: Oracle's NVL(var1, 'value')  will take care of empty string ' ' replacement.  T-SQL's Isnull(var1, 'value') doesn't.

Answer (score 30):

You can simply do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   yourTable
WHERE  yourColumn IS NULL OR yourColumn = ''
```

Answer (score 26):

```
SELECT *
FROM   TableName
WHERE  columnNAme IS NULL OR 
       LTRIM(RTRIM(columnName)) = ''
```

Comment: SELECT *
FROM   TableName
WHERE  columnNAme IS NULL OR RTRIM(columnName) = ''

Comment: As Xavier points out, there is no need to do BOTH `ltrim` and `rtrim` if the goal is merely to compare to empty string. REASON: if there is ONLY whitespace, a single trim will remove all of it. For example, you don't care whether the comparison fails because what remains is "abc" or "   abc".

Comment: Technically the `trim` functions remove _spaces_, not _whitespace_ — at least, so says the documentation.

Answer (score 8):

To find rows where col is `NULL`, empty string or whitespace (spaces, tabs):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(col)),'')=''
```

To find rows where col is `NOT NULL`, empty string or whitespace (spaces, tabs):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(col)),'')<>''
```

Answer (score 8):

**Some [sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable) methods...**

```
SELECT *
FROM #T
WHERE SomeCol = '' OR SomeCol IS NULL;

SELECT *
FROM #T
WHERE SomeCol = '' 
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM #T
WHERE  SomeCol IS NULL;

SELECT *
FROM #T
WHERE EXISTS ((SELECT NULL UNION SELECT '') INTERSECT SELECT SomeCol);
```

**And some non-sargable ones...**

```
SELECT *
FROM #T
WHERE IIF(SomeCol <> '',0,1) = 1;

SELECT *
FROM #T
WHERE NULLIF(SomeCol,'') IS NULL;

SELECT *
FROM #T
WHERE ISNULL(SomeCol,'') = '';
```

Answer (score 4):

my best solution :

```
 WHERE  
 COALESCE(char_length(fieldValue), 0) = 0
```

COALESCE returns the first non-null expr in the expression list().

if the fieldValue is null or empty string then: we will return the second element then 0.

so 0 is equal to 0 then this fieldValue is a null or empty string.

in python for exemple:

```
def coalesce(fieldValue):
    if fieldValue in (null,''):
        return 0
```

good luck

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
FROM   Table
WHERE  column like '' or column IS NULL OR LEN(column) = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`isnull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function to get both `null` and empty values of a text field:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE isnull(my_nullable_text_field,'') = ''
```

Comment: The isnull function literally just checks if the value is null. It will not work if the string is empty(" ").

Comment: @Max Pringle. I do not state differently. Also the provided code address the question request. Not sure on your contribution. Suggest an edit instead of downvoting.

Comment: will take your advice. I put in a suggested edit now.  This where clause only gets the null values not the empty string values. A nullif could be used to  get the empty values.

Answer (score 3):

This is ugly MSSQL:

```
CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL([Address1], ''))) <> '' THEN [Address2] ELSE '' END
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
   isnull(column,'') column, * 
from Table  
Where column = ''
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ***in*** as another method

```
Select *
From Table
Where column in(null, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
--setup
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#T') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #T;
CREATE TABLE #T(ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #T (Name) VALUES('JOHN'),(''),(NULL);
SELECT * FROM #T
 1  JOHN
 2  -- is empty string
 3  NULL
```

You can examine `''` as `NULL` by converting it to `NULL` using `NULLIF`

```
--here you set '' to null
UPDATE #T SET NAME = NULLIF(NAME,'')
SELECT * FROM #T 
 1  JOHN
 2  NULL
 3  NULL
```

or you can examine `NULL` as `''` using `SELECT ISNULL(NULL,'')`

```
-- here you set NULL to ''
UPDATE #T SET NAME = ISNULL(NULL,'') WHERE NAME IS NULL
SELECT * FROM #T
1   JOHN
2   -- is empty string
3   -- is empty string

--clean up
DROP TABLE #T
```

Answer (score 1):

In sproc, you can use the following condition:

```
DECLARE @USER_ID VARCAHR(15)=NULL --THIS VALUE IS NULL OR EMPTY DON'T MATTER
IF(COALESCE(@USER_ID,'')='')
PRINT 'HUSSAM'
```

Answer (score 1):

by this function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[isnull](@input nvarchar(50),@ret int = 0)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

    return (case when @input='' then @ret when @input is null then @ret else @input end)

END
```

and use this:

dbo.isnull(value,0)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM DBO.AGENDA
WHERE 
  --IF @DT_START IS NULL OR EMPTY
  ( ISNULL( @DT_START,'' ) = '' AND DT_START IS NOT NULL ) -- GET ALL DATE
  OR --ELSE
  ( DT_START >= @DT_START ) --FILTER

-- MORE FILTER

SELECT * FROM DBO.AGENDA
WHERE 
  ( ( ISNULL( @DT_START,'' ) = '' AND DT_START IS NOT NULL ) OR ( DT_START >= @DT_START ) ) 
  AND
  DT_END < GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

youe check null With IS NULL and string Empty  With LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(Column))) = 0
in

```
SELECT *
FROM AppInfra.Person
WHERE   LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(NationalCode))) = 0 OR  NationalCode IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it in SELECT section can use like this.

```
SELECT COALESCE(column1, column2) AS columnName
FROM tabel;
```

if column1 is null column2 will be return

Answer (score 0):

if you want to fetch empty and null values from one column then this code apply

```
select columnname2 from tablename
where columnname2 is null or columnname2 = '';
```

select columnlist from table you want to fetch then where in which column you want to fetch values of null then write columnname is null and also you want to find empty values then write perticular column name then = '' this will show that empty values from perticular column

Comment: select columnname from tablename
where columnname2 is null or columnname2 = '';

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**