# Does it make sense to put IS NULL / empty string comparison into procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-function

while doing select in MS SQL very often NULL and '' can be treated identical.
There is good description to Combine These:
[how to use null or empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663207/how-to-use-null-or-empty-string-in-sql)

However I wonder if it make sense to put this into a user defined function to simplify queries for this. Does anybody uses such function? Are there strong pro and cons on this one?

Comment: Putting this is a UDF (as simple as it is) could be a performance killer

Comment: It depends on your data as well. In some cases `''` and *`NULL`* may not represent the same thing. As a **very** simple idea, you could have a Yes/No question on your website/application. Values of `''` could represent that the customer has not answered the question, when it was presented to them, however, *`NULL`* may represent that the customer hasn't answered and it isn't applicable, or they haven't been given the opportunity (perhaps they registered before the question was added). I would never say yes `''` and *`NULL`* represent the same thing without knowing the data they represent.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti also raises a good point. I no doubt imagine the "easiest" way to add a UDF for this would be to use a Scaler, as it goes in the `WHERE`. Scalar functions, however, are notoriously slower compared to Table-Value Function, but then it could look messy in your `FROM` clause. Personally, if you know that for that column *`NULL`* also means `''` use an `OR` clause: `AND (YourColumn = '' OR YourColumn IS NULL)`. Or, otherwise, if you don't wants NULLs, then use an `UPDATE` statement to change the *`NULL`* values to `''` and then set the column to be non-NULLable.